# AngularJS checkboxes selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, checkbox

I am using the following code for some checkboxes. I want to select multiple items and when I submit is storing on DB but when I check on of those boxes the name of my item is disappear and there is my angular can't read that my option was checked.

This is my HTML

```
<label 
ng-repeat="live in lives"
name="live" >
    <input 
    type="checkbox" 
    ng-model="live" 
    value="{{ live.id }}"> {{live.name}} 
</label>
```

And this is my AngularJS where I have this function as soon as this things are done my ADD button become active so I can push it on DB.

```
$scope.goodToGo = function() {
        return ($scope.description && $scope.release && $scope.demo && $scope.client > 0 && $scope.type > 0 && $scope.live > 0);
    };
```

There's anyone who has any idea how to fix this problem?

EDIT

Actually it read my first checked and is pushing on DB but not the others.

Comment: name attribute is same for the all `checkboxes` causing an issue, try `name="live-{{$index}}"`

Comment: so what you suppose to do?

Comment: it should be unique for each field `name="live-{{$index}}"`

Comment: even like this is doing the same thing, even if I delete that name attribute is same

Comment: could you please create a fiddle or plunkr?

Comment: Ok, I will try on fiddle

Comment: I used to follow this example which is getting data from a string http://plnkr.co/edit/U4VD61?p=preview

Comment: There is not data. Is showing only the checkboxes which can't be accessed

Comment: It should be `<label ng-repeat="(live,val) in lives" name="live" > <input type="checkbox" ng-model="live[live]" ng-value="live.id"> {{live.name}} </label> `

Comment: could you provide me the sample json of `lives` variable..so that I can play fiddle it